# web scraping with python/beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So i am learning how to web scrape. I am currently trying to find all of the social links in this code

```
    <ul class="socials">
   <li class="social instagram">
    <b>
     Instagram:
    </b>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/keithgalli/">
     https://www.instagram.com/keithgalli/
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="social twitter">
    <b>
     Twitter:
    </b>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/keithgalli">
     https://twitter.com/keithgalli
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="social linkedin">
    <b>
     LinkedIn:
    </b>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/keithgalli/">
     https://www.linkedin.com/in/keithgalli/
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="social tiktok">
    <b>
     TikTok:
    </b>
    <a href="https://www.tiktok.com/@keithgalli">
     https://www.tiktok.com/@keithgalli
    </a>
   </li>
```

It is clearly the links in the anchor tags but i am having issues with the find_all command and when i try to use it i am only getting back one of the social links. The code im putting in is

```
href = soup.find_all("a")
print(href)
```

and the out put is

```
[<a href="https://keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html">keithgalli.github.io/web-scraping/webpage.html</a>]
```

I am not exactly sure on what i am doing wrong. I thought that if i targeted the href that it would grab all of the hrefs..Any hints or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the `soup` variable at this point? How are you passing this HTML to beautifulsoup?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for href in soup.find_all("a"):
    print(href)
```

Comment: so i tried that command and it still only grabbed  the one href that my above code grabbed. Looking tho now at the code im trying to sift through there are a lot of anchor tags and i think i just need to be more specific on which ones..